# Is there a way to make the LaTeX labels appear in the .pdf (say as a note)?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

**Here's some background:**
I have multiple chapters in the dissertation I am writing. I have LaTeX-labelled the figures, the table and the equations.  Whenever I add a chapter, I create a `.pdf` of the entire manuscript written till that point, and then I use it as a source of references (talking material) for the subsequent chapters.

**The problem:**
Say if in `Chapter 6` I need to talk about a figure in `Chapter 2`, I have to open the code document and then hunt for the particular figure label. This task would be immensely simplified if there were some way (perhaps a package) which would add sticky-notes (which seem to be quite common in most PDF readers) to all the labelled elements. The sticky-notes then can be scripted to contain the labels. Of course, for the final documents I will need to disable this feature to reduce the clutter of the sticky-notes.

If you can think of some other workaround to achieve the same end, please let me know as well.

Comment: Yeah that `showkeys` should work... thanks for the link...
In this case (and in similar cases) is it advisable that the OP delete the question?

Comment: Good question...I think that it is up to you. One reason for leaving it here is that your version of the question may show up more often in searches, in which case your question will direct people to the answer - and stop the question being asked again. For what it is worth, I was only able to find the post above because I already knew the answer...